# Add/pass new field to MVC Membership CreateUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Developing MVC4 application and using Register that comes with MVC5 framework.
I updated `register.cshtml` and added a new column called `Language`.
I also updated the `RegisterModel` class to hold my value.
Register model has all the values including my property (language).

Now I like to grab this values from Register Model and plug into `CreateUser`.

MyProperty is model.Language

```
[HttpPost]
publıc ActıonResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status)
}
```

What would be the best way to grab this value and store in database?
I really like to store in `Users` table where `UserID` and `UserName` exists.

Comment: See http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.osbornm.com%2Farchive%2F2010%2F07%2F21%2Fusing-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx&ei=9L6MUPneMsn8iwLmroDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNGdR1bs-Ux7auj6WpDz8rZyPOJMHg&sig2=7Gh0P6AXL3RTlrLpzrn3CA and jon galloways simplemembership. There is no MVC5 framework.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the syntax for passing the additional column(s) via the `WebSecurity.CreatUserAndAccount` call. Try this:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName,model.Password,
new {Language = model.Language
});
```

It's fully described [here](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/#comment-408).